Mockito not able to mock the RestTemplate exchange
I am using restTemplate mock in my test case and unable to mock in the code. Tried with the call but no success
Please find the test case as below:
when(restTemplate.exchange(any(), eq(HttpMethod.POST), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(MemberDataValidationResponse.class)))
.thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok(mockResponse));
@Test
public void testValidateMemberData_Success() throws Exception {
    MemberValidationRequest memberRequest = new MemberValidationRequest();
    memberRequest.setCorelationIdentifier("123");

    MemberDataValidationResponse mockResponse = new MemberDataValidationResponse();
    mockResponse.setStatus("200");

    HttpHeaders headers = SelfServiceValidation.populateTokenHeaders();
    HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(new JSONObject(memberRequest).toString(), headers);
    
    when(restTemplate.exchange(any(), eq(HttpMethod.POST), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(MemberDataValidationResponse.class)))
            .thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok(mockResponse));
    MemberDataValidationResponse response = new MemberDataValidationResponse();
    
    
     try (MockedStatic<SelfServiceDaoHelper> mockStatic = mockStatic(SelfServiceDaoHelper.class)) {
         
         mockStatic.when(() ->SelfServiceDaoHelper.auditApiRequestData(any(MapSqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(1);
                 
     assertEquals(1, SelfServiceDaoHelper.auditApiRequestData(new MapSqlParameterSource()));
     MemberDataValidationResponse result = SelfServiceValidation.validateMemberData(memberRequest);
     response = result;
     
     };
    
    assertNotNull(response);
    assertEquals("200", response.getStatus());
}

This is the actual method below :
public static MemberDataValidationResponse validateMemberData(MemberValidationRequest memberValidationRequest)
        throws Exception {
    MemberDataValidationResponse memberValidateResponse = new MemberDataValidationResponse();
    try {
        if (isSelfServicePortalServerAvailable(selfServicePortalURL)) {
            String corelationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            String spanId = corelationId + SelfServicePortalConstants.MEMBER_VALIDATION_CODE;
            HttpHeaders headers = populateTokenHeaders();
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            String validateMemberAPI = selfServicePortalURL + Endpoints.MEMBER_VALIDATION;
            log.info("Self Service Portal API URL :{}", validateMemberAPI);
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(memberValidationRequest);
            String requestBody = jsonObj.toString();
            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);
            processRequestAudit(memberValidationRequest, corelationId, spanId, ipAddress.toString(),
                    "Member Validation", "Claim Submission");
            UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(validateMemberAPI);
            ResponseEntity<MemberDataValidationResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                    builder.buildAndExpand().toUri(), HttpMethod.POST, request, MemberDataValidationResponse.class);
            memberValidateResponse = (MemberDataValidationResponse) response.getBody();
            processResponseAudit(memberValidateResponse, "", spanId, corelationId);
        } else {
            log.info(SELF_SERVICE_PORTAL_UNAVAILABLE_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (Exception cause) {
        throw new RuntimeException(cause);
    }
    return memberValidateResponse;
}


It is perfectly capable of mocking it, the problem is you are using a new RestTEmplate each time. Don't do that, inject one into the class and re-use.

It is the static method because of that need to make it.

Well you cannot mock things that are created internally. Make the method non static and inject an instance.

I am understanding what you said but i can't change the method. is it possible to do this test case using powermockito

If you need to revert to Power Mockito that is, in my book, a sign your design is wrong. Why is it impossible to update your code to make it right? I'm always stumped by those remarks.

This question is similar to: Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

but i can't change the method please do not change your requirements mid question. If thats how this goes, most of us wont bother answering your question since you keep changing the question for every answer. If you want people to help you, you post all your requirements up front, and if you already have decided on what solution you want, you include that in your question too.

The method call is written by another team and unable to update that. Thanks for suggestions. Will request them to update.

I would really try making an effort and refactor this code, passing the restTemplate in and potentially the base URL if you can rely on spring-boot test features such as @RestClientTest.
However, if you have to stick with the current implementation, perhaps you can get around by using Mockito MockedConstruction feature, see: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#49
e.g
try (MockedConstruction mocked = mockConstruction(RestTemplate.class)) {
    RestTemplate restTamplate = new RestTemplate();
    when(restTamplate.exchange(...)).thenReturn(...);
}

